# Setting custom property as href in a Partial View

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I've created a document type called "Article" that has a textstring property called "Link" that holds a URL to an external site. I'm trying to create a simple PartialView that will include a hyperlink to that URL. If I simply display the URL in the partial view, it displays properly. If I try to reference it inside an href attribute, it renders as "Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.PropertyResult". The code is below. What obvious thing am I missing that will greatly shame me once you point it out?

```
    @foreach (var item in selection)
            {

                <dt>
                    <a target="_blank" href='@item.GetProperty("link")'>@item.Name</a>
                </dt>
                <dd>@item.GetProperty("linkDescription") <br />
                    @item.GetProperty("link")
                </dd>
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting was sufficient for me to find the obvious answer so I may humiliate **myself**. Instead of GetProperty, I switched to GetPropertyValue.

Comment: Or you could just use @item.Link because item is a DynamicNode

Comment: Or @item.GetProperty("link").Value :-)

Comment: @dampee,I had tried that and it resulted in an error, oddly!

Comment: if item.GetProperty("link") is null it can throw an error indeed